# How to access the object returned from $save in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

the object returned is of this type

```
d {$$state: Object}
  $$state:Object
   status:1
   value:g
    $promise:undefined
    $resolved:true
    id:5271
    name:"insidious"
```

$$state is a private method in angular. I need the id ?

Comment: You'll want to show what you did to get this value. I think you're talking about the `$save` on [`$resource`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource), which looks like you're supposed to send a callback function to... I'd suggest carefully reading that documentation.

Comment: var savedMovie = vm.saveMovie.$save({
                    type: 'genres'

                },function (thing) {
                        // all global variables become undefined here
                 console.log(this);
                       console.log(thing);
                });

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a [mcve].